# Logarithms in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, logarithm

Please tell me how you can change log(e) to 1. And in general is there a way in sympy to get a float-type answer?
For example, instead of log(2), get 0.69314718056

```
from math import *
from sympy import *

x1=symbols('x1')
x2=symbols('x2')
Func = e**(2*x1)*(x1+x2**2+2*x2)
print(Func.diff(x2))
```

Here I already get log(e). In other calculations, the same situation

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html) help? Also, log(e) =/= 1. ln(e) = 1.

Comment: Oh, no, I tried, it changes in some places, but not everywhere.
Try this expression
    Func.diff(x1)

Comment: That gives me `2.0*2.71828182845905**(2*x1)*(x1 + x2**2 + 2*x2) + 2.71828182845905**(2*x1)`.

Comment: I'm writing code in Google Colabortory, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Colab should not make a difference. As an aside, this is why `from modulename import *` syntax is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing the `math` module and `sympy`. This leads to "inconsistent" results. Note that in your code, `e` comes from the `math` module, and it is just the number `2.71828182845905`. SymPy also exposes the Euler's number, but it is called `E`, which is a symbolic entity.

Hence, when working with SymPy, try to use as many SymPy objects as possible. Your expression becomes:

```py
Func = E**(2*x1)*(x1+x2**2+2*x2)
```

By using SymPy objects, canonical simplifications are possible: `log(E)` gives `1`.

If you want to convert "symbolic numbers" to floating point, you can use the `n()` method. For example `log(2).n()` gives `0.693147180559945`.